# How to implement a class that has a significantly different implementation in one case?

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures

I am trying to implement a data structure to manage n-dimensional vectors where n will not be greater than 50.

The problem is that **n = 2** is a special case which has the same interface, but a completely different implementation. How can I implement this?

I was considering making **n** a template parameter and:

1. Make a partial template specialization for n = 2
2. Copypaste the interface for n = 2
3. Construct the data structure using a factory which will have prototypes of this structure instantiated for n = 2, 3, ..., 50

Is there a better way? What should I be careful about in case I implement it as I suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on whether `n` is known at compile time or only at runtime.

If `n` is known at compile time, then partial template specification is the way to go (in the same spirit as the implementation of `std::vector<bool>` is a template specification).

If `n` is known only at runtime, you can implement a [*State Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) to keep an object internal to your vector that performs the actions, make two implementations of it, and hide a pointer to its instance inside the vector object:

```
struct Vector;

struct VectorOperations {
    virtual void doOperation1(Vector& v) = 0;
    virtual void doOperation2(Vector& v) = 0;
};

struct VectorOperationsTwo: VectorOperations  {
    virtual void doOperation1(Vector& v);
    virtual void doOperation2(Vector& v);
} opsTwo;

struct VectorOperationsThreeAndMore: VectorOperations {
    virtual void doOperation1(Vector& v);
    virtual void doOperation2(Vector& v);
} opsThreeAndMore;

class Vector {
    VectorOperations *ops;
public:
    Vector(int size) {
        ops = size == 2 ? (VectorOperations*)&opsTwo : &opsThreeAndMore;
    }
    void operation1() {
        ops->doOperation1();
    }
    void operation2() {
        ops->doOperation2();
    }
    friend class VectorOperationsTwo;
    friend class VectorOperationsThreeAndMore;
};
```

This example assumes that vectors of two elements and vectors of more than two elements will have the same data members, so I made `opsTwo` and `opsThreeAndMore` shared. If this is not the case, you can allocate new `VectorOperationsTwo` or `VectorOperationsThreeAndMore` inside the constructor.

Comment: I would actually refer to the *Strategy Pattern* here, because once set it does not changes any longer. The *State Pattern* refers to a strategy that evolves with time: it is closely related to a State Machine (from which it inherits its name).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Well, in this case it could be a strategy or a state, depending on the rest of the API. If the size is set in the constructor and never changed again, it's a strategy; if we let vectors change their size after creation and adjust our strategy object accordingly, it would become a state. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 3):

IMO a factory that delivers one implementation for the special case n=2 and a different implementation for all other cases is the simplest and most elegant way to implement that.

Comment: Thank you! Now that I am thinking about it what should be the factory return type?

Comment: It depends on the class hierarchy. If the special case of n=2 is implemented as a subclass of the more general class (n!=2), then the general class is the return type. If both n=2 and n!=2 are subclasses of a (possibly abstract) superclass, then that superclass is the return type.

Answer (score 1):

I suposse that the container dimensions are known at runtime, so teplate-specialization-based solutions not works.

What about the [PIMPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) idiom? Store two implementations, one for the general case, and one for the special case.

Comment: N is here the dimension, not the size.

Answer (score 1):

Partial template specialization. The shared parts of the interface can be inherited from a non-templated (or at least non-specialized) base class.

The reason is that dimensionality of data is very much NOT a runtime variable, but domain-dependent.